# Visual Studio: How to re-add the code bar in the editor?

Tags: visual-studio

Somewhere along the way recently, apparently during an update, good ol VS decided to entirely nuke my highly customized layout (again, for the billionth time over the years) and turned off that bar that sits at the top of the code editing window, that shows where you are in the code, and lets you easily select/create another event (etc.) in the code window... I'm not even sure what it's officially called (which makes finding it's setting that much harder, lol).

It's the thin bar that usually sits right here:

[image]

Anyone know where/how to re-enable it?

Comment: You see two splitted code window? If I have two window and grab middle horizontal splitter and move up at the edge it show me this icon on right.

Comment: I think you're talking about the "navigation bar" (not 100% sure though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you looking for, I hope :)
[image]

Comment: Thanks, you're mistaking VSCode for Visual Studio though. I'm asking about the full-on Big Daddy, Visual Studio. =)

Comment: @J.ScottElblein, sorry my bad I'll update the answer

Comment: Bingo! "Navigation bar", I'll hafta try and remember that, lol. ty